# Vaadin With Grails

Tags: java, mysql, grails, vaadin

I am new to `vaadin`, couple of days back i have downloaded `vaadin` dashboard demo application.

http://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard/ `vaadin quickticket demo application`

And i found it amazing and become a fan of vaadin.

I am `swing` developer and about to start new project using `vaadin`. I am confused about database communication to `vaadin`. I am using `MySql` database.

As i did not stared writing code, can some one guide me which approach would be best.

1. Use `vaadin` with `grails`

   - fast in development use `spring` and `hibernate`. Do it impact any performance as there is number of layer?
   - I have no idea about `grails`, if it best with `vaadin` then i will learn it.
2. Directly use `TableQuery` and `SQLContanier`.
3. Use `Hibernate` independently to fetch the data from database.
4. Use `JSON` and make `api` call to another `webservices` to get the data . as the `vaadin quickticket demo application` is doing.

Which approch should i use or can anyone guide me which could be the best practices with `vaadin` with `MySql` database.

Should i used `grails` with `vaadin` i am developing dashboard application for tracking inventory. Will it cause any major issue with performance or speed.

Comment: there is no silver bullet for this.  is your data model already modeled?  are there already hibernate configs?  are you planning on using the `Table` component or just want to show some html?  i doubt you will get sane advice without telling your exact problem.

Comment: i am using `mysql` as a database currently this database is getting used by `C# frontend`. now i want to migrate my application into `java web based` application. i can say i am writing this application from scratch with same database `DDL and proc`. so i will have write all DAO and services logic and all again, and i am open to write it again :) . So i need advice on this should i go with `grails + vaadin` so in future i don't need to migrate again. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: you might first look into GORM http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html if mapping your data is feasable or worth the efford (gorm features vs hastle to do the mapping).  serving domain (domain in grails means DAO and related methods) as JSON/XML is rather easy - but it is not very usuable for a "common" vaadin up, which usually uses only server-side-code.  if you have lots of data going into selects/tables you might end up write a container in vaadin, that maps into gorm -- or you write all your DAO for yourself using groovy's sql http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html

Comment: will it make any difference if i use `SQLContainer` or `GORM` ? as of now `GORM` is having learning curve for me but i have gone through couple of blog,  people suggest `GORM` is good if you learn it and it will help you in fast development. do you think `GORM` can used in place of `SQLContainer`? what about performance ?

Comment: there simply is no silver bullet.  GORM will make it easier to deal with you writing data scentric services -- sqlcontainer will only help you with wiring data into the UI.  and for performance: measure it!  there is no technology out there, that some stupid useage can not bring down to a grinding halt.  no one will be able to give you even guesswork with the given infos.

Comment: so which approach would you recommend as a high level prospective ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59631/discussion-between-user3336168-and-cfrick).

Comment: You might also want to look at the [JPAContainer](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/jpacontainer.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to go with `vaddin7 + grails` as this provide good support for `ORM` and logging , CURD opration  so i don't need to write all database logic from begin.

Comment: Based on your comments, you might want to read https://www.gitbook.io/book/ondrej-kvasnovsky/vaadin-on-grails. There is a way how to use SqlContainer, Attaching session with GORM, how to use Groovy Sql.